RL exception: while launch the turtlebot on custom world
I want to launch the Turtlebot on my custom world. I followed this to launch the file. However, I received the error RLException:[turtlebot_world.launch] is neither a launch file in package [gazebo_project] nor is [gazebo_project] a launch file name. The traceback for the exeception was written to the log file.
I summarized the command here that I used for the task
$roscd turtlebot_gazebo/launch/
:~/robot_ws/src/turtlebot_simulator/turtlebot_gazebo/launch$ cp turtlebot_world.launch ~/ros_gazebo/src/gazebo_project/launch/
$cd ros_gazebo/src/gazebo_project/launch
:~/ros_gazebo/src/gazebo_project/launch $ gedit turtlebot_world.launch
:~/ros_gazebo/src/gazebo_project/launch $ roslaunch gazebo_project turtlebot_world.launch

The last command threw the error. How can I solve it?
